# how to query bookshelf without getting the name of the column

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This is my table.

```
CREATE TABLE `information_yourself` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `body` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

INSERT INTO `information_yourself` (`id`, `title`, `body`)
VALUES
    (1, 'test1', 'content1');
    (2, 'test2', 'content2');
    (3, 'test3', 'content3');
    (4, 'test4', 'content4');
```

this is my query using the node module bookshelf

```
router.get('/', function(req, res){
information.where({id:1})
.fetch({ columns: ['body'] })
.then(function(model){
  var obj = JSON.stringify(model);
  var str = obj.replace(/[\[\]\{\}]+/g, '');
  res.render('test.ejs', {str});
})
```

})

The result is '"body":'content1'.

How do i receive just the result 'content 1' without the result retrieving the column name?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this line

```
 var obj = JSON.stringify(model);
```

To

```
 var obj = JSON.stringify(model['body']);
```

This may helps !